# Can't find my mistake! error: expected identifier before '(' token

Tags: c++, c

This is my main code, I did search related mistakes before asking but it just doesn't seem wrong...The IDE says the error is in line 11.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float sal;
    printf("Digite o salário bruto: ");
    scanf("%f",&sal);
    if(sal<=2246.75){
       printf("Salário líquido :  ",sal);
    }
    else{
        if(sal>2246.75)&&(sal<2995.70){
            printf("Salário Líquido: ",sal * 0.925);
        }
        else{
            if(sal>2995.70)&&(sal<=3743.19){
                printf("Salário Líquido: ",sal * 0.845);
            }
            else{
                printf("Salário Líquido: ", sal * 0.775);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, pick a language.

Comment: when defining literal numerics to be 'float', use a decimal point AND a trailing 'F'.  Without the trailing 'F', the compiler will see those numeric literals as 'double'.  Note: the 'F' can be upper or lower case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(sal>2246.75)&&(sal<2995.70){
```

The problem is that the *entire* condition must be placed within a set of parentheses.

It's fine if you want to further enclose the sub-conditions, but you must surround the entire lot, too:

```
if ((sal > 2246.75) && (sal < 2995.70)) {
```

Comment: It's conditional statement / if-statement / if-condition not "condition". This is misleading as condition is simply with the likes of `x > y && x != z`

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `if` statement has to correct as follows, here you were missing bracket() for `if`.

   `if( (sal>2246.75)&& (sal<2995.70)){`
2. You have to specify the formatter for `printf` correctly as follows; here you are missing type formatter.

   `printf("Salário Líquido: %f", sal * 0.775);`

Both these errors are there in multiple occasions in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser although i must say that i copied a version without that %.2f. I got it fixed with the extra '('

Comment: @MatheusAlves you are not supposed to edit question after received answer

Comment: ok sorry, should I take it back? It was just because my question wasn't around the %f so I though it could mislead peoplo who were having the same problem...

Comment: @MatheusAlves It is better. http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c/1765#1765

Answer (score 1):

there are actually two major kinds of problems with the posted code.

```
printf("Salário líquido :  ",sal);
```

is missing a format specifier for the 'sal' variable

it should be:

```
printf("Salario liquido : %f", sal);
```

Note: each of the printf() statements have this same problem

```
if(sal>2246.75)&&(sal<2995.70){
```

is missing the outside parens

it should be:

```
if( (sal>2246.75) && (sal<2995.70) ) {
```

Note: I added some horizontal spacing for clarity only

the last two 'if' statements have this same problem

Suggest compiling with all warnings enabled.

For gcc, at a minimum, use '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic'

main always returns an 'int'

To avoid that return code being a random value, always end the function with:

```
return(0);
```

Comment: I posted a version without the "%f", its not that I actually missed, but the rules prevent me from changing the original code...anyway, thanks for the anwser, I did get the code to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think that  `if(sal>2246.75)&&(sal<2995.70)` is supposed to be
  `if(sal>2246.75 && sal<2995.70)`.